# display content using get posts from terms under a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a custom taxonomy say "project-type" which is registered for the custom post "projects" and under that I have terms "catOne" and "catTwo". Now I want to display all the custom posts that are linked to catOne using the term_id of "catOne", which in my case is 9.

So I am successfully able to loop through all the posts but it is displaying only the ID but not all contents.

**My approach:**

```
$cat_id = 9;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( $cat_id )
        ),
    ),
);

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> <?php post_class(); ?>">
        <h1 class="posttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <div id="post-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>

   </div>

   <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Output I am getting**

```
<div id="post-137 class=" ""="">
        <h1 class="posttitle"><a href=""></a></h1>
        <div id="post-content">
                </div>
   </div>
    <div id="post-135 class=" ""="">
        <h1 class="posttitle"><a href=""></a></h1>
        <div id="post-content">
                </div>
   </div>
```

Can someone please help me with where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `post_class()`, `the_permalink()`, `the_title()`,  and `the_excerpt()`, you should use the `$post` object to get the data, just like you did with `$post->ID`. The functions you've used should be called only if you're using a [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) based on `have_posts()`. You aren't, so replace them with:

- `post_class()` -> [`get_post_class( '', $post->ID )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_class/)
- `the_permalink()` -> [`get_the_permalink( $post->ID )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)
- `the_title()` -> [`$post->title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)
- `the_excerpt()` -> [`$post->post_excerpt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)